# WPF- Mouse Over effect not taking place

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a set of buttons created in WPF. I am adding two triggers to the buttons, MouseOver and IsPressed. However , only the IsPressed trigger is working but not the MouseOver effect. I want to be able to highlight the button with mouse cursor and then it changes to a different color. What did I miss?

XAML:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="Border" >
     <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                   </Border>
                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

              <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                            </Trigger>

           <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
     <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="10,10,0,0"/>

              </Trigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

EDITED:

```
<Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">

                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10,10,0,0">

                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>

                    </Trigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing TargetName="Border" in your DarkGoldenrod trigger.

Comment: I did it a different way but now the background has dark blue color when ispressed kicks in

Comment: different how? Dark blue color when pressed in without you specifying it suggests to me you're using the default template and modifying it?

Comment: Right now, the mouse over effect takes place elsewhere, I believe it's by default by windows. And I just needed the sunken effect from IsPressed

Comment: When the effect kicks in, it seems there is a dark blue just outside the edge of the button (top and left). I need to kinda make it transparent .

Comment: I notice that IsPressed is modified via Style triggers and not ControlTemplate triggers now. Are you still using the same template in your original post? DId you modify it? Remove it completely? A screenshot of your issue might help too.

Comment: Do you mind moving this discussion to chat? Would be easier.

Comment: And yes I did remove the template and modified it.